# Multiple inputs in java at once

Tags: java

I have written a program that converts an infix expression to a postfix expression. However, I need to take multiple inputs and stop when I find a 0.

What I have is,

Input: (3+4)*(3-1)

Output: 4 + 3 1 - *

What I need is,

Input:

(3+4)*(3-1)

(3*4)-(3*1)

(3+4)*(3-1)

(3+2)*((3-3)

(3+4)*(3-1)

0

Output:

4 + 3 1 - *

4 * 3 1 * -

4 + 3 1 - *

Syntax Error

4 + 3 1 - *

End

The code is:

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = input.readLine();
    String pf = new String();
    int i=0, check=0;
    Stack<Character> s1 = new Stack<>();


    while(i<s.length())
    {
        if(isOperand(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            pf += s.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(isOperator(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            while (!s1.empty() && s1.peek() != '(' && compareOperators(s1.peek(),s.charAt(i)) <= 0)
            {
                pf += ' ';
                pf += s1.peek();
                s1.pop();
            }
            pf += ' ';
            s1.push(s.charAt(i));
        }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == '(') 
        { 
            s1.push(s.charAt(i));
        }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') 
        {
            check++;
            while (!s1.empty()) 
            {
                if ((char)s1.peek() == '(') 
                { 
                    check--;
                    s1.pop(); 
                    break; 
                }
                pf += ' ';
                pf += s1.peek();
                s1.pop();
            }
        }
        i++;
    }


    while (!s1.empty()) {
        if(s1.peek()=='(')
            check--;
        pf += ' ';
        pf += s1.peek();
        pf += ' ';
        s1.pop();
    }
    if(check!=0)
        System.out.println("Syntax Error");
    else
    {
        System.out.println(pf);

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you should separate input logic from conversion logic first. Extract your algorithm into a method that takes an expression String as argument and returns the converted expression as String. Then you might see the solution by yourself!

Comment: You need to call `input.readLine()` more than once.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with your expectations; you should expect `(3+4)*(3-1)` to result in `34+31-*`.  Yours are missing that extra `3`.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't copy the 3 in all those outputs. They're there in my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that your code for infix to prefix conversion in a separate function.

```
public void convert(String s) {
    String pf = new String();
    int i=0, check=0;
    Stack<Character> s1 = new Stack<>();


    while(i<s.length())
    {
        if(isOperand(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            pf += s.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(isOperator(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            while (!s1.empty() && s1.peek() != '(' && compareOperators(s1.peek(),s.charAt(i)) <= 0)
            {
                pf += ' ';
                pf += s1.peek();
                s1.pop();
            }
            pf += ' ';
            s1.push(s.charAt(i));
        }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == '(') 
        { 
            s1.push(s.charAt(i));
        }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') 
        {
            check++;
            while (!s1.empty()) 
            {
                if ((char)s1.peek() == '(') 
                { 
                    check--;
                    s1.pop(); 
                    break; 
                }
                pf += ' ';
                pf += s1.peek();
                s1.pop();
            }
        }
        i++;
    }


    while (!s1.empty()) {
        if(s1.peek()=='(')
            check--;
        pf += ' ';
        pf += s1.peek();
        pf += ' ';
        s1.pop();
    }
    if(check!=0)
        System.out.println("Syntax Error");
    else
    {
        System.out.println(pf);

    }

}
```

Then in the main function:

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s;
    while(true) {
        s = input.readLine();
        if (s.equals("0"))
            break;
        else 
            convert(s);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
    String s = input.readLine();
```

with

```
    String s;
    while(!(s = input.readLine()).equals("0")){
```

and then put an extra bracket at the very end. Now, you are reading each line in with `(s = input.readLine()`, and making sure it doesn't equal 0 with `!s.equals(0)` before using it each time.